# Flattening a list containing subslists

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I'm trying to get my solution to a problem to pass the online judge on Leetcode. The problem is: Given a nested list of integers, implement an iterator to flatten it.

Each element is either an integer, or a list -- whose elements may also be integers or other lists.

Example 1:
Given the list [[1,1],2,[1,1]],

By calling next repeatedly until hasNext returns false, the order of elements returned by next should be: [1,1,2,1,1]

The full problem is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-nested-list-iterator/description/).

The problem states that it will instantiate the class that is implemented using the following code:

```
# Your NestedIterator object will be instantiated and called as such:
# i, v = NestedIterator(nestedList), []
# while i.hasNext(): v.append(i.next())
```

Below is my solution:

```
class NestedIterator(object):
    currIdx = 0

    def __init__(self, nestedList):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        :type nestedList: List[NestedInteger]
        """
        newFlattenedList = []
        self.flattenList(nestedList, newFlattenedList)
        nestedList = newFlattenedList
        self.flattenedList = nestedList

    def flattenList(self, nestedList, flattenedList):

        for ele in nestedList:
            if type(ele) == list and ele  > 0:
                self.flattenList(ele, flattenedList)
            else:
                flattenedList.append(ele)
        return

    def next(self):
        """
        :rtype: int
        """
        if self.hasNext():

            test = self.flattenedList[self.currIdx]
            self.currIdx +=1
            return test
        else:
            return NULL 

    def hasNext(self):
        """
        :rtype: bool
        """
        nextIdx = self.currIdx + 1 
        return True if nextIdx <= len(self.flattenedList) else False
```

When I run this code in an IDE with the input [[1,1],2,[1,1]], I get an output of [1,1,2,1,1]. For some reason, when I run the code with the online judge, given the input [[1,1],2,[1,1]], the output is [[1,1],2,[1,1]] is returned. Why is the leetcode online judge returning something different?

Answer (score 1):

You meant `None` not `NULL` right?

```
def next(self):
    """
    :rtype: int
    """
    if self.hasNext():

        test = self.flattenedList[self.currIdx]
        self.currIdx +=1
        return test
    else:
        #return NULL 
        return None
```

By running:

```
nestedList = [[1,1],2,[1,1]]
i, v = NestedIterator(nestedList), []
while i.hasNext(): v.append(i.next())

print v
```

I got:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```

So, other than changing NULL to None, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has 2 problems.

1. Change return NULL to None in next method.
2. In flattenList the size comparison for ele only works in Python 2! Add the len() function for it to work on Python 3.

Here is the modified code. This should run everywhere.

```
class NestedIterator(object):
    currIdx = 0

    def __init__(self, nestedList):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        :type nestedList: List[NestedInteger]
        """
        newFlattenedList = []
        self.flattenList(nestedList, newFlattenedList)
        nestedList = newFlattenedList
        self.flattenedList = nestedList

    def flattenList(self, nestedList, flattenedList):

        for ele in nestedList:
            if type(ele) == list and len(ele)  > 0:
                self.flattenList(ele, flattenedList)
            else:
                flattenedList.append(ele)
        return

    def next(self):
        """
        :rtype: int
        """
        if self.hasNext():

            test = self.flattenedList[self.currIdx]
            self.currIdx +=1
            return test
        else:
            return None

    def hasNext(self):
        """
        :rtype: bool
        """
        nextIdx = self.currIdx + 1
        return True if nextIdx <= len(self.flattenedList) else False
```

Comment: It's still not working when I submit on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-nested-list-iterator/description/). Is it working for you?